# what is the default provider of Puppet package resource

Tags: mysql, ruby, puppet

This is the code that puppet to download and install mysql. But where the package is downloaded from, or what is the default provider for this package in different Operation System?

```
package 
{ 'mysql-server':
  require => Exec['apt-update'],        # require 'apt-update' before installing
  ensure => installed,
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the package repository or the package installation executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `package` resource without explicit provider Puppet tries to figure out what provider should be used based on facts.

At the start Puppet gathers facts about system, operating system and what is available to use. Based on those facts it will use provider that is most likely to work.

You can see what facts are required for every provider to work in the `package` documentation page: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#package-providers